# How to develop a custom SonarQube plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

We are satisfactorily using SonarQube as part of the pipeline of our product, and lately an idea had emerged of creating a customized plugin in SonarQube that will scan our code for PII leaks. (e.g, if we find 'email' inside the argument of a .log function we will inform the user).
Is such a thing possible? Can anybody please give guidance or a plugin creating guide? Couldn't find anything good online.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How to develop a custom plugin is documented in [the SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/extend/developing-plugin/).

> scan our code for PII leaks. (e.g, if we find 'email' inside the argument of a .log function we will inform the user)

If the e-mail address would be hardcoded in the code, you shouldn't have any problems to create a rule which detects it. If it would be read from a property file and next passed to the method, then I'm not sure if it is possible to detect it.